# Proof of Pick's theorem for triangular case

Tags: geometry

From the formula of area $S$ of triangle formed by $(0,0),(a,b),(c,d)$, $S=\frac{1}{2}|ad-bc|$.

The minimum value of $S$ is $S=\frac{1}{2}$ when $|ad-bc|=1$.

From Pick's theorem, when $|ad-bc|=1$, there is no grid point in the triangle or on the segment of triangle. Can we prove this directly? If there is no grid point on the line, we get $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(c,d)=1$. This is the requirement of $|ad-bc|=1$. Thus, I want to get the requirement of no grind in the triangle. How to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear map with matrix $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$ transforms the integer lattice $\Bbb Z^2$ into itself and maps $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ into $(0,0)$, $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$. So the inverse of $A$ maps $S$ to $T$ with vertices 
 $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and it is apparent this has no lattice points
in the interior. As $A$ maps $\Bbb Z^2$ bijectively to itself, then $S$ has
no interior lattice points either.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove $\gcd(a,b)=1$, $\gcd(c,d)=1$, and $\gcd(a-c,b-d)=1$.

For the first one: suppose $a$ and $b$ had a common factor, say $x$. What could we say about $ad-bc$?

The second one should be similar. For the last one you might want to notice that
\begin{align}(a-c)d-(b-d)c&=ad-cd-bc+cd\\
&=ad-bc\end{align}
(Does this have a geometric interpretation?)